# What is the meaning and impication of one-element-too-large array/queue?

Tags: algorithm, arrays

just wondering what it is.

Edit: I know it's not a type of array but just a feature. So what does it mean by one-element-too-large ?

Comment: Perhaps I have not understood the question. Are you encounter too-big arrays in existing code, or have you been instructed to build one?

Comment: Like dmckee, I'm not sure what the question is asking.  Maybe you could clarify by providing some context?  For example, if this is part of an error message, how exactly did you find it, and what is the full message?  Or if it's from a book, what is the section about, and is said about this phrase?

Answer (score 1):

Misunderstanding of language specific indexing conventions?

Answer (score 0):

Intent to use a "end of data" marker?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the classic fence-post/fence-panel counting problem?